# adding and deleting userinput in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add user's name in the Tic Tac Toe game I am working on, I am using form, when I push submit the players name do not show up under Player 1 and Player 2?  Can I not use form? Also how do I delete the names from both fields once the user hits Clear.  Would the Clear code not work?  I have it commented out right now.  I tried several things but nothing has worked. FYI I am still learning so please don't be harsh.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tictactoe.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1><center>Tic Tac Toe</center></h1>
<script src="tictactoe.js"> </script>

<h3>Enter Player's Name</h3>
<h2>First Player is the X, Second player is the O</h2>

<form action="players">
    <label for="p1name">Player One First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
    <label for="p2name">Player Two First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname2"><br><br>
</form>

<button onclick="players()">Submit</button>
<button onclick="Clear()">Clear</button>

<h4>Player One, (X) </h4><p id="demo"></p>
<h4>Player Two, (O) </h4><p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("p1name").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("p2name").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
}

// function Clear() {

// var elements = [] ;
// elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myText");

// for(var i=0; i<elements.length ; i++){
//    elements[i].value = "" ;
// }

// } 
function Clear(){
    document.getElementsById("myText").value = '';
}

</script>

<div class="selectTokens">
<h1>X</h1>
<h1>O</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    padding: 30px;
}
.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Your button calls a function named `players`. Where is it?

Comment: Also, the `center` tag [is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: They mistakenly forgot to change `MyFunction` to `players` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You have problemes in:

- myFunction() should be: players() because this is the name you used to trigger it in the on click handler
- the input IDs p1name, p2name (does not exist in the HTML) should be: fname, fname2 (the ones used in the inputs ID)
- document.getElementsById("myText").value = '';
  `getElementsById` width `s` does not exists

instead select each input alone using and sets their value to ""

`document.getElementsById("fname").value = '';`

`document.getElementsById("fname2").value = '';`

Try this code:

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    padding: 30px;
}
.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tictactoe.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1><center>Tic Tac Toe</center></h1>
<script src="tictactoe.js"> </script>

<h3>Enter Player's Name</h3>
<h2>First Player is the X, Second player is the O</h2>

<form action="players">
    <label for="p1name">Player One First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
    <label for="p2name">Player Two First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname2"><br><br>
</form>

<button onclick="players()">Submit</button>
<button onclick="Clear()">Clear</button>

<h4>Player One, (X) </h4><p id="demo"></p>
<h4>Player Two, (O) </h4><p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
function players() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("fname2").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
}

// function Clear() {

// var elements = [] ;
// elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myText");

// for(var i=0; i<elements.length ; i++){
//    elements[i].value = "" ;
// }

// } 
function Clear(){
    document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
    document.getElementById("fname2").value = "";
}

</script>

<div class="selectTokens">
<h1>X</h1>
<h1>O</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so how do I delete from 

Player One, (X)


Player Two, (O)

fields?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        <center>Tic Tac Toe</center>
    </h1>

    <h3>Enter Player's Name</h3>
    <h2>First Player is the X, Second player is the O</h2>

    <div>
        <label for="p1name">Player One First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="p1name" name="fname"><br><br>
        <label for="p2name">Player Two First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="p2name" name="fname2"><br><br>
    </div>

    <button type="button" onclick="initPlayers()">Submit</button>
    <button type="" onclick="Clear()">Clear</button>

    <h4>Player One, (X) </h4>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <h4>Player Two, (O) </h4>
    <p id="demo2"></p>

    <script>
        function initPlayers() {
            var player_1 = document.getElementById("p1name").value;
            var Player_2 = document.getElementById("p2name").value;

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = player_1;
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = Player_2;

            var player_1 = document.getElementById("p1name").value = '';
            var Player_2 = document.getElementById("p2name").value = '';
        }

        function Clear() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = '';
        }
    </script>

    <div class="selectTokens">
        <h1>X</h1>
        <h1>O</h1>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
                <div class="grid-item"></div>
            </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```